# Django template view to prevent a user defined relative url

Tags: html, django

In a `Django` template, I render a URL stored in a database. This URL is defined by the user. What I do not like is that the user defines a relative URL such as `/admin` and redirect to somewhere irrelevant within the current server domain. Is there any way to prevent `bookmark.url` being rendered as relative URL? I want it to be rendered as an absolute path only.

```
<div>
    <a href="{{ bookmark.url }}">{{ bookmark.name }}</a>
</div>
```

**Note 1**: `{% get_static_prefix %}` looks irrelevant to my question. Please avoid linking to those questions. (Just in case)

**Note 2**: I am after any solution in the template view side or an HTML solution. I know modification of the model object before sending it as a `context` is always possible. But, I am not after such solutions. Also, I do not like to put an if-else inside the view too because it is too much for such a minor improvement.

Comment: It is not clear how that would solve your issue. Couldn't the users define the URL as `http://example.com/admin`?

Comment: @Selcuk, Yes. any absolute URL is ok. I want URLs are being rendered as absolute and nothing relative.

Comment: There is (and cannot be) a built-in way. In that case you may consider writing your own template tag.

Comment: In your urls file you need to make sure that you add admin before this view. Order matters.
You also need to make a blacklist of urls you don't want to happen when a user trys to create it it doesnt allow it. Also, make sure you validate that the url provided is a proper url if it is being sent out from your site.

Comment: You want to convert relative URLs to absolute URLs when rendering? Even if the absolute URL is somewhere else in your app?

Comment: @IainShelvington, That's a very good point. But, for now, I just want to ensure all URLs are rendered as absolute than relative.

Comment: Are you happy to create a custom tag?

Comment: @IainShelvington, Ideally not. But, if there is no other solution, that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following custom tag should work

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def absolute_url(context, url):
    return urljoin(context.request.build_absolute_uri(), url)
```

[`urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) will turn a fully qualified URL and a relative path into a fully qualified URL with the path replaced by the right hand argument

```
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('http://somewebsite.com/foo/bar/', '/hello')
'http://somewebsite.com/hello'
```

But if the right hand argument is already a fully qualified URL it will just return that

```
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin('http://somewebsite.com/foo/bar/', 'http://someotherwebsite.com/')
'http://someotherwebsite.com/'
```

Then when you have loaded your custom tag you can use it like so

```
<a href="{% absolute_url bookmark.url %}">
```